# DeepLab v3 - how to process images with any size ratio. (h * w)

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning, deeplab

Deeplab v3 predicts only with default ratio 512 * 512. how to process images with different size ratio.

**please look over the error:-**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 35, in 
>       predicted = model_dlv3.predict(img[np.newaxis, ...])
>
> File
>   "/home/developer/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1149, in predict
>       x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
>
> File
>   "/home/developer/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 751, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')
>
> File
>   "/home/developer/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
>   line 138, in standardize_input_data
>       str(data_shape))
>
> **ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have shape (512, 512, 3) but got array with shape (2448, 3264, 3)**

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the images to 512*512 or turn images into a square using padding and then resize them into 512*512. Latter option is better since it won't change the shape of the objects inside the image. You can use different padding modes and see what gives the best result.

You can use opencv or scikit-image for resizing and padding

opencv documentation for padding: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder

scikit-image documentation for padding : http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.pad

Comment: Main problem is image size, we need to produce image with any size.